# chilkat SetSslCertRequirement server validation

Tags: chilkat

Im using activex version 9.5.0.79 with ftps on port 990.

If I use following code snippet (server, logon etc is already set):-

```
loftp.authTls=0
loftp.authssl=0
loftp.ssl=1 
loftp.RequireSSLVertVerify=1
loftp.SetSllClientCert(loClientCert)
lnSuccess=SetSslCertRequirement("ServerCN", "test.test.com")
lnSuccess=loftp.connect()
```

It seems to work lnsuccess=1 for the connect even if the server's SubjectCN is "fred.fred.com"

I can of course get the server certificate as per your example

> https://www.example-code.com/foxpro/ftp_verifyServerCert.asp

and check it manually but wondering why the requirement wasn't honoured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Rob,

This new build fixes the problem:
32-bit: https://chilkatdownload.com/prerelease/chilkatax-9.5.0-win32-1604.zip

This will be noted in the v9.5.0.80 release notes (and v9.5.0.80 is due out before the end of October).  The above pre-release URL will not remain valid forever..